# Is it possible to make GC manage native object's lifetime?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, java-native-interface, native

With C++ and C# experience and some little Java knowledge I'm now starting a Java+JNI (C++) project (Android, if that matters).

I have a native method, that creates some C++ class and returns a pointer to it as a Java long value (say, handle). And then other native methods called from Java code here and there, use the handle as a parameter to do some native operations on this class. C++ side does not own the object, it's Java side who does. But in the current architecture design it's hard to define who exactly owns the object and when to delete it. So it would probably be nice to make Java VM garbage collector to manage the object's lifetime somehow. The C++ class does not consume any resources, except some piece of memory, not large. So it's OK, if several such objects will not be destructed.

In C# I would probably wrap the native IntPtr handle in some managed wrapper class. And override it's finalizer to call native object's destructor when the managed wrapper is garbage collected. SafeHandle, AddMemoryPressure, etc. might be also of help here.

This is a different story with Java's finalize. The second thing you know after 'Hello world' in Java, is that using finalize is bad. Are there any other ways to accomplish this in Java? Maybe using PhantomReference?

Comment: Using a finalizer is "bad" in C# for the same reason it's bad in Java - so what's the difference?

Comment: See what BlueRaja said ;-) C# uses `IDisposable` and Java often uses `Closable` interfaces. These define the contracts of the lifetime -- but are manual constructs. (C# supports `using`, Java7 will support something similar.) The "issue" with both C# and Java is that the GC used (in the current implementations) *is not* reference counting and is a lazy mark/sweep hybrid -- that is, the actual time of GC is "non-deterministic" for the sake of general argument. The problem with finalizers or any *Reference's is that **they can not "see" the pressure on other system resources**.

Comment: @pst: No the real problem is that you can't guarantee that finalizers will be run before the VM is shutdown and you could solve this problem trivially (at least how it's implemented in Java) for every GC algorithm. And I don't see what pressure on other system resources has to do with it - if the object is still in use you can't free it and if it's not a full GC will always find and free it (now that the VM doesn't care about anything but memory is true, but that again could be fixed if that'd be a problem)

Comment: As I've said, I have only a little Java knowledge, so I may not see all the exact reasons of why the finalize is 'bad' in Java. As to C#, it is not considered as bad. At least, e.g., Richter's CLR via C# has a whole chapter "Using Finalization to Release Native Resources". Also, such methods as GC.AddMemoryPressure, or HandleCollector classes, shows that it was actually intended by .NET team to use finalizers to manage native resources.

Comment: @Alex Che: Not read that book, but if you handle resources in a finalizer that are not automatically released when the OS shutdowns a process (<-- should be obvious why handles are therefore no "real" problem although it's considered bad practice in win32 programming), that's **EXTREMELY** dangerous and bad advice. There's a reason the .NET team added the IDisplosable interface and it wasn't "Well it'd be fun to collect resources differently"

Comment: Also, being a C++ programmer, I'd learned IDisposable pattern earlier it was actually introduced to C# (see RAII). I love this pattern, but it only goes for trivial resource management cases, where lifetime of an object does not leave the block boundary.

Comment: @Voo, that's right, but in my case it's just a memory, that will be released automatically on process shutdown.

Comment: @Alex And that's why I and several other people have already said that it's not a problem in your case..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well let's consider the reason WHY finalize and Co are problematic: As you know there's no guarantee that the finalize will be called before the VM is shut down, which means that special cleanup code won't necessarily run (imo a bad decision, I don't see any problems to run through the finalize queue at cleanup, but well that's how it is). Also this is exactly the same situation in C#

Now your objects only consume memory, which will be cleaned up by the OS anyhow when the VM is destroyed, so the only case where finalize is problematic won't matter for you. So yes you can indeed use this variant and it'll work perfectly fine, but it may not exactly be considered a great architectural design - and as soon as you add resources to your C++ code where the OS doesn't handle the cleanup correctly you will run into problems

Also note that implementing a finalizer results in some additional overhead for the GC and means it takes two cycles to cleanup one of these objects (and whatever you do, don't ever save an object in the finalize method)

Comment: Fair enough. However, since the GC is independent upon external "pressure" it might not release objects as aggressively as it could (ignoring the fact that a finalizer may never be called at all) -- this can lead to "out of resource" situations when external resources are added to the mix. One example is the ByteBuffer with a direct allocated buffer.

Comment: Thanks Voo. So my problem was that I did not understand all the exact reasons behind the 'finalize overriding is bad' rule. Ratchet Freak and Konstantin Komissarchik gave essentially the same answers, but since your answer is the first and at the same time more detailed, I'm accepting it.

Comment: @pst, I've created a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716582/gc-addmemorypressure-equivalent-in-java . Could you please collaborate?

Answer (score 2):

If you understand why you should avoid using Java's finalize method, you will also understand how to use it correctly. Using finalize for closing system resources (files and handles) is bad because you don't actually know when those resources will be closed and released. Using complex finalize logic is bad as your object reference can leak out and get pinned in memory again.

For your scenario, it is perfectly fine to use finalize.

Answer (score 1):

using a wrapper with a finalizer is a decent solution here

but if you really don't wanna do that you can use a PhantomReference with a ReferenceQueue to clean it up (but you are going to require a separate thread to poll the queue)

Answer (score 0):

So how can we achieve it using phantom reference.

1. Create a wrapper object for your native intPtr object. Create a
   phantom reference(with a  reference queue) on the wrapper object.
2. Create and maintain a map of phantom reference to intPtr.
3. Create a thread that will be monitoring the reference queue for finalized
   wrapper object instances.
4. This thread will get the phantom reference from reference queue, lookup intPtr using phantom reference and call destructor on native int object referenced by intPtr.
5. While all this happening, you can go about happily using the
   wrapper object in your java code.